# Duplication between YAML.register_class() and yaml_object(yml)()?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

While researching ruamel.yaml (https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html), I noticed that registering a class can be done using either `YAML.register_class()` or `@yaml_object(yaml)`. Additionally it seems the implementations of the two functions are nearly identical, down to the internal function names.

I am under the impression that this `@yaml_object(yaml)` always can be replaced by `@yaml.register_class` (i.e. using the object method as a decorator. And while retaining backwards compatibility, I think `@yaml_object(yaml)(cls)` could be reimplemented as `return yaml.register_class(cls)`, and thereby reducing code duplication.

Example:

```
import sys

from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@yaml.register_class
@dataclass
class Asdf:
    foo: int
    bar: int

yaml.dump(Asdf(1,2), sys.stdout)
```

prints

```
!Asdf
foo: 1
bar: 2
```

Are there any cases where this would not work? Or is this something the package's author missed?

Comment: Why are you addressing this in the second person? It sounds like you'd be better off posting on the [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues?status=new&status=open)

Comment: I considered posting in the bug tracker, but it has a warning: "This is issue tracker is for tracking issues (i.e. bugs) and feature requests. All usage related questions, including cases where you are not sure whether it is a bug or faulty usage of the library, should be posted on http://stackoverflow.com and tagged yaml and ruamel.yaml (I will be notified of these posts)."

Comment: @jimbo1qaz Thanks for asking this here. As is obvious, you are not entirely sure if this could be a feature request, so you were entirely correct in not creating an issue on bitbucket. It sounds like not everyone has read the [new issues guidelines](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/new) as well as you did.

Comment: @Anthon the "close" votes are accumulating (3 out of 5, as of 19 hours after asking the question). I'm not sure if StackOverflow allows these kinds of questions, or if I should edit the question to say this doesn't belong in the issue tracker.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz You should certainly not edit the question, such discussions don't belong in a question on [so]. The first thing you asked in your question is "why" and you seem to be addressing me directly, that is often a bit problematic. If you would give the example and ask if there are cases in which you should use `yaml_object` instead of using the method, then it is a question about code. (But it still might be closed because there are always people having a different opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible, but that is only now that `register_class` actually returns the `cls`.

This return of `cls` was introduced 2018-07-12 with the resolution of [issue #186](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/186/).

If you do:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

def yaml_object(yml):
    return yml.register_class


@yaml_object(yaml)
class Asdf:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

yaml.dump(Asdf(1,2), sys.stdout)
```

it gives:

```
!Asdf
foo: 1
bar: 2
```